# Massive differences between Google Analytics and own data collection

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, usage-statistics

The use of a web app is to be evaluated statistically. It has been publicly available since spring of this year.

The web app is linked to *Google Analytics*. The following is done for the own user data collection:

A *Unique User ID* is created when the web app is called for the first time. It is stored in the *localStorage* and is compared each time the page is called up again.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("uuid") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("uuid", get_uuid());
}

function get_uuid() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  )
}
```

This data is written to a database together with other information (concrete page, time, device type, etc.). Users without *Javascript* or *localStorage* will not be included; however, they will probably not be able to use the web app correctly anyway.

If I now compare the data from *Google Analytics* with my own variant, the discrepancy is considerable.

- Different users according to *Google*: about **900**
- Different users due to *UUID*: about **400**

Additionally about **100** visits (or interactions) without *UUID* were registered.

Now my question is why these big differences exist. In my opinion, my data collection should be pretty accurate. But maybe I have a thinking error with the approach of the *UUID*? Or could it be that *Google* counts quite differently; for example, any robots that don't leave a *UUID* behind?

Thank you very much for your answers and considerations.

Comment: You don't list what your own data says, or did I miss that?

Comment: @Andreas According to my own data based on the UUID, about 400 users visited the web app. Google estimates it to be about 900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure you have encountered Google Analytics (GA) spam.
This is because GA is JavaScript and your ID is listed in the html source.

So anyone who wants to create spam on your data can use your ID.
Why you ask... When you notice it you see that there are webpages listed you don't know in your GA data, you (the admin) open them and get a virus or worse.
Don't open the webpages...

There are as far as I know two ways to fix it. Regex filter wich is a common way.
All webpages that has refferals from other domains you don't "know" you need to block.
This takes time and is not a good approach.

My method is to pass a dimension from the html to GA.
If that dimension is missing the data is not real.

Your JavaScript probably looks something like:

```
.....
 ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

If we add a dimension which we pick up in GA admin tools

```
.....
 ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1':  'FooBar'
    });

</script>
```

Go to admin -> Property (the middle column) and at the bottom you have `Dd Custom Definitions`.
Open Custom Dimensions and add the dimension you added to the html.

Now you can set up a filter in the view tab of GA admin to only show data with your custom dimension "FooBar".

Any data that does not have this "FooBar" is spam that is not generated from your webpage.

Just remember you need to change all GA JavaScript codes and add the dimension.

---

You can see this spam (if I'm correct) in the Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Referrals report.
If you see Sources that you don't recognize and looks odd it's most likely the spam.
Before I used this method my Referrals looked something like this, there is about 50 of these fake referrals.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, everyone can view the GA ID via JS. That's why I understand your approach.

But if I look at the referrals report, there are less than 1% of dubious pages: 
- 770 users (85%) come directly to the web app 
- 105 users (11%) come via Google 
- 28 users (3%) come via another website I know of 

So even if I use a Regex filter or implement your variant with the "FooBar" dimension, the differences (between GA and my UUID data) still seem to be immense.

Comment: The UUID is determined randomly (see script in original post). The probability that several users have the same UUID should therefore not exist. However, I took over the code and did not write it myself. Nevertheless I checked it as much as possible: I used several devices for the test and deleted my UUID/localStorage manually to see if it behaves as it should. Everything worked fine and the way I imagined it to work.

Comment: Your function, as it's posted doesn't work so therefor I can't test it. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in /in/YRvsI on line 4`

Comment: I copied the code 1:1 again into a .html within the <script> tag and it works for me. Unfortunately I can't tell why you get this error message.

Comment: The code does not seem to work with IE. Since the web app is only mobile, this is negligible. According to the GA, all visitors only use Android and iOS: Most likely without IE mobile.